# Datapower - Error de validación con XSL

Tags: java, xml, xsl

Estimada Comunidad,

Estoy validando un **XML** con un **XSL** que me han entregado (*no deseo modificar el XSL*), pero al momento de validar el mismo, lanza un error propio de una *declaración del XSL de validación*.

**Error:**

> Error on line 35 of ValFactura.xsl:   XTDE1425: Cannot find a matching
>   1-argument function named
>   {http://www.datapower.com/extensions}variable()   in built-in template
>   rule

**Código JAVA:**

```
   try {
            OutputStream os = new PrintStream(System.out);
            xsl.process(xmlFile, xslFile, os);
   } 
   catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
   }

private void process(Source xml, Source xsl, Result result) throws TransformerException {
        try {
            Templates template = factory.newTemplates(xsl);
            Transformer transformer = template.newTransformer();
            transformer.transform(xml, result);
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException tce) {
            throw new TransformerException(tce.getMessageAndLocation());
        } catch (TransformerException te) {
            throw new TransformerException(te.getMessageAndLocation());
        }
    }
```

**Extracto XSL:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions" 
    xmlns:func="http://exslt.org/functions" 
    xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" 
    extension-element-prefixes="dp" exclude-result-prefixes="dp" 
    version="1.0">
```

....

```
<xsl:variable name="numeroRuc" select="substring(dp:variable('var://context/cpe/nombreArchivoEnviado'), 1, 11)"/>
```

....

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Librería:**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
     <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
     <version>9.5.1-5</version>
</dependency>
```

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

El espacio de nombres xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions" me parece que es la causa del problema. No se si sea un dominio de tu red interna, ya que lo he pegado en el explorador y me redirecciona a una pagina de ibm. Pero debería contestar un XSD o un DTD donde estén definidas las validaciones del espacio xmlns:dp. Si es un dominio interno, tal vez no estés llegando a el o haya cambiado de sitio.

Comment: El Namespaces xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions", es propio de Datapower de IBM, si buscamos en la ayuda de Datapower (https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS9H2Y_7.2.0/com.ibm.dp.doc/xsltandxpath_extensions.html), hace mención sólo a su uso como Namespaces, y desconozco el por qué no reconoce el método "variable", siendo que la Ayuda lo hace.

¿ Hará falta alguna librería para que funcione ?

Comment: En la url de ayuda de datapower dice `The DataPower compiler supports all extensions from the XSLT 1.0 and XPath 1.0 specifications. ` Entonces mi pregunta es `¿Estas usando el compilador de Datapower para procesar este xml?` Según esa documentación ese Namespace será encontrado si usas el compilador de Datapower.